# Sum of certain letters occurrences in alphanumeric string using Excel

Tags: excel, parsing, match, string-matching

I have an array of alphanumeric data used in application testing, and for certain reasons I need to calculate a **sum of occurrences of letters from "a" to "f"** in each string (this will be used for further data processing):

```
02599caa0b600 --> should be 4
489455f183c1fb49b --> should be 5
678661081c1h
66410hd2f0kxd94f5bb
8a0339a4417
f6d9f967ts4af6e
886sf7asc3e85ec
03f1fhh3c3a2am
e491b17638m60
1m8h2m07bhaa4tnhbc4
29ma900a80m96m65
ca6a75f505tsac8
956828db8ts7fd1d
cf1d220a59a7851180e
a8b7852xd9e7a9
b85963fbe30718db9976
39b8kx8f85abb1b6
0xxb3b648ab
a8da75f730d45048
588h69d344
```

This is what strings look like, their length is about 10-30 symbols, and I suppose to have about **3-5k** of them daily for processing. Assumptions and limitations:

1. Case of letters does NOT matter (happily).
2. The list of letters may change one day, but very much likely still remains a **range**, e.g. a-k, d-g, etc. - therefore solution should be as much flexible as possible.
3. Any temporary calculations / ranges are not prohibited, but the shorter the better.
4. I'd prefer pure Excel solution, but in case it's too complicated - VBA still an option. Nevertheless, complicated Excel formula is better than "2-lines-of-code" VBA - if the 1st works as expected.

Things I've tried so far (as I noticed, that practice here is very much welcome):

- Searched through already answered questions, but found no Excel-based solutions for anything similar. Other languages / approaches are not an option (except VBA).
- The best thing I got on my own so far are nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions, but it's dirty and very straightforward. Assuming the range may change to c-x that'll be a nightmare.
- I'm not a newbie to Excel, but things like complicated array formulas are still hard nuts for me - alas but true...

Anyway, I do not ask for "ready-to-go" "out-of-box" solution - I ask for help and right direction / approach for self-learning and further understanding of similar problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone who contributed. You all guys are brilliant, I could not even expect such helpful and detailed answers. +100 to SO!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my option - pretty similar to already posted, but anyway... especially if you're interested in learning, which is so rare today)

Assuming you have your list starting A2, use the following array formula:

```
=SUM(LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT(CODE("a")&":"&CODE("f")))),"")))
```

Just as reminder - press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Some explanations:

1. Range of letters a-f is generated using char codes of range edges, transformed back to the array of chars using `CHAR(ROW(INDIRECT(...)))` structure.
2. Then "nightmare" comes to help, finally summarizing the obtained numbers of substituted vs original string subtractions.
3. Thus, in case of such double conversion you do not need codetable)))

And two more similar "nuts" samples - just for learning purposes.

In case you need to summarize all **digits matches** - you still may use the above using 0 and 9 as input (digits are chars with 48 to 57 codes starting 0). However, the following more simple solution will go as well:

```
=SUM(LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,ROW($1:$10)-1,"")))
```

The trick here is that we may generate numbers 0-9 using array or row numbers 1-10 **minus** 1 - `ROW(0)` would generate an error.

Finally, if you need to calculate a **sum of all digits** in the string - use this:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(VALUE(MID($A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($A2))),1)),0))
```

Here we disintegrate the initial string to letters using `MID` for every single char, and then test it against being a number using `IFERROR` and returning 0 for anything but digit.

Last 2 are (obviously) your beloved array nuts)))

I use the above samples in my Excel training for QA stuff (by the way welcome to SE, colleague!), thus demonstrating typical functions / approaches for nuts cracking. Hope that was useful for you as well. However, all the previous answers deserve at least your fair upvote, especially @barry's nuts-free recipe)

For your convenience sample file is shared: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qo5k479oyawkrzh/SumLettersCount.xlsx

Good luck with your testing)

Comment: +1 for "nuts free recipe"! and lots of good info......for summing all digits (a little off-topic?) I prefer to extend the LEN(SUBSTITUTE) solution, i.e. `=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"")),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})`

Comment: @barryhoudini you're welcome buddy) by the way, I always tend to simplify the syntax of my formulas and avoid "hardcoded" values - such as manual arrays. Perhaps you see some disadvantage (except seeming complexity for beginners) in using array formulas and constructions similar to my samples? I learned such techniques from Walkenbach and his bibles...

Comment: @PeterL. Thans sooooo much for such detailed and thorough explanation! I accept your answer for the efforts and provided sample. Digits count and array formulas "look inside" are just the thing I need for nuts crack)

Answer (score 6):

You can use SUBSTITUTE without nesting multiple SUBSTITUTE functions, e.g. with text string in A1 this formula in B1 will count all letters a to f (upper or lower case)

`=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),{"a","b","c","d","e","f"},"")))`

for a lengthier list of letters like c to x you could use this version to avoid listing them all

`=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),CHAR(96+ROW(INDIRECT("3:24"))),"")))`

3:24 represents letter 3 (c) to letter 24 (x) so you can easily change that to 1:26 for all letters or 15:25 for o to y etc.

Comment: +1 for just the same. I'd accept your answer as well, but Peter's explanations are very much appreciated for my learning. Nevertheless, your solution is perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This formula assumes that your data is in column A, the first letter of the range you are looking for is in F1, and the last letter in G1. It needs to be entered as an array formula and then copied down to the bottom of your data.

```
  =SUM(--(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>=UPPER($F$1))*--(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<=UPPER($G$1))).
```

Note that if the range of letters you are for changes, you would need to change the first letter of range in cell F1 and the last letter in G1.

If you are sure that the number of characters in any of the strings will not exceed some maximum number, say 50, then the formula can be simplified to:

```
  =SUM(--(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW($1:$50),1))>=$F$1)*--(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW($1:$50),1))<=$G$1))
```

Comment: Could you please briefly explain / provide a link for understanding the purpose of `--` symbols?

Comment: @PeterL.: `--` negates twice, i.e. returns the same result - but has the positive side effect of casting boolean TRUE/FALSE to numbers 1/0! Thus, in a lot of array formulas, this is the shortest way to make a sum across only one condition. If you have multiple conditions, the `*` operator takes care of the coercing, so no need to use it then.

Comment: @PeterAlbert thanks, my +1 for the explanation. I learned so much on my own from this Q)

Comment: ....but in this case the * which multiplies the two arrays, implicitly co-erces, so the -- can both be removed and formula will still work as before

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in column A, try this formula:

```
=SUM(--NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW($1:$99),1),"abcdef"))))-99+LEN(A1)
```

Enter the formula as an array formula, i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.